# MySQL Order by date and grouping by name

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, sql-order-by

**Table**

```
mysql> select * from temp;
+--------+---------------------+
| name   | created_at          |
+--------+---------------------+
| second | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 |
| first  | 2020-01-01 12:10:00 |
| second | 2020-01-01 12:20:00 |
| third  | 2020-01-01 12:30:00 |
| third  | 2020-01-01 12:40:00 |
| first  | 2020-01-01 12:50:00 |
+--------+---------------------+
```

In the above example, I want to order by `created_at` first and show rows with the same name.

So I trying to ordering with created_at, name.

```
mysql> select * from temp order by created_at, name;
+--------+---------------------+
| name   | created_at          |
+--------+---------------------+
| second | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 |
| first  | 2020-01-01 12:10:00 |
| second | 2020-01-01 12:20:00 |
| third  | 2020-01-01 12:30:00 |
| third  | 2020-01-01 12:40:00 |
| first  | 2020-01-01 12:50:00 |
+--------+---------------------+
```

But it does not grouping name.

After searched about order by, I found that in the case of the second column, it is applied only to the result of the first order by.

**Desired result**

```
+--------+---------------------+
| name   | created_at          |
+--------+---------------------+
| second | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 |
| second | 2020-01-01 12:20:00 |
| first  | 2020-01-01 12:10:00 |
| first  | 2020-01-01 12:50:00 |
| third  | 2020-01-01 12:30:00 |
| third  | 2020-01-01 12:40:00 |
+--------+---------------------+
```

How can I manipulate query to achieve it?

Comment: What is the ordering logic behind your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to order by minimum `created_at` of every named group first then order by `created_at`.

```
SELECT name, created_at
FROM TEMP tem
ORDER BY
    (SELECT MIN(tem2.created_at)
     FROM TEMP tem2 
     WHERE tem.name = tem2.name), created_at
```

Bellow part will get minimum `created_at` for name group of every row's name

```
SELECT MIN(tem2.created_at)
         FROM TEMP tem2 
         WHERE tem.name = tem2.name
```

Now every group is ordered by the group's minimum `created_at` and then order every group name's by `created_at`.

Answer (score 1):

You could join this table with a subquery of the minimal `created_at` per name, and order by that:

```sql
SELECT   t.name, created_at
FROM     mytable t
JOIN     (SELECT   name, MIN(created_at) AS min_created_at
          FROM     mytable
          GROUP BY name) m ON t.name = m.name
ORDER BY min_created_at, t.name, t.created_at
```

Comment: You should probably also add `t.created_at` to the end of the `ORDER BY`

Comment: Not sure why this didn't get an upvote... I was going to post exactly the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can just use window `min()` for ordering:

```
select *
from temp
order by 
    min(created_at) over(partition by name), 
    created_at
```

The window `min()` gives you the minimum `created_at` across all records that have th same `name`.

In earlier versions, I would use a correlated subquery directly in the `order by` clause:

```
select *
from temp t
order by
    (select min(t1.created_at) from temp t1 where t1.name = t.name),
    created_at
```